# file_get_contents not saving to an array

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have a section in my code which uses file_get_contents to grab the url from the given web page. I also have a section in my code which scans the titles in each link value in my array. 
I want  end up having an array similar to this :

```
Array(
  Google => array(
    [title] => Google
    [link] => http://www.google.com
  )
)
```

but no values are saved to my array, even though i can't detect any errors

```
$links = Array();

$URL = 'http://www.theqlick.com'; // change it for urls to grab  
$file = file_get_contents($URL);
// grabs the urls from URL 
if( strlen( $file )>0 ) {
    $links[] = preg_match_all( "/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/", $file, $links);
}

function Titles() {
    global $links;
    $str = implode('',array_map('file_get_contents',$links));
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

    $titles = Array();
    if( strlen( $str )>0 ) {
        $titles[] = preg_match_all( "/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/", $str, $title );
        return $title;   
        return $links;
    } 
}
$newArray = array();

$j = 0;

foreach( $links as $key => $val ){
    $newArray[$key] = array( 'link' => $val, 'title' => $title[1][$j++]);
}

print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: Don't assign the return value of `preg_match_all`, that's not how it works. What is this `Titles` function doing here when you're not calling it anywhere, and why does it have two `return` statements?

Answer (score 0):

The following code does not seem to return anything

```
$links[] = preg_match_all( "/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/", $file, $links);
```

Try the following

```
$links = Array();

$URL = 'http://www.theqlick.com'; // change it for urls to grab
$file = file_get_contents($URL);
// grabs the urls from URL
if (strlen($file) > 0) {
    $links[] = preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $file, $links);
}

var_dump($links);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtmll/DTD/xhtmll-transitional.dtd' (length=55)
      1 => string 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' (length=28)
      2 => string 'http://www.theqlick.com' (length=23)
      3 => string 'http://www.theqlick.com' (length=23)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string 'd' (length=1)
      1 => string 'l' (length=1)
      2 => string 'm' (length=1)
      3 => string 'm' (length=1)
  2 => int 4
```